# HBase WAL file and HDFS data staging

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs

How I understand what is WAL:
Write Ahead Log provides consistent put/delete operations. All operation is written to it before making change in region. If something goes wrong with the region server we can repair information from WAL.

What I didn't understand is how WAL is implemented on top of HDFS?

From HDFS documentation :

> A client request to create a file does not reach the NameNode
>   immediately. In fact, initially the HDFS client caches the file data
>   into a temporary local file. Application writes are transparently
>   redirected to this temporary local file. When the local file
>   accumulates data worth over one HDFS block size, the client contacts
>   the NameNode. The NameNode inserts the file name into the file system
>   hierarchy and allocates a data block for it. The NameNode responds to
>   the client request with the identity of the DataNode and the
>   destination data block. Then the client flushes the block of data from
>   the local temporary file to the specified DataNode. When a file is
>   closed, the remaining un-flushed data in the temporary local file is
>   transferred to the DataNode

So it's possible to loose WAL content if I made a small change and its content isn't forwarded to hdfs yet?

**EDIT**:
As I understand from:
http://hadoop-hbase.blogspot.com.by/2012/05/hbase-hdfs-and-durable-sync.html

we could force  hdfs client to sync data without waiting it became equal to block size.

Answer (score 0):

The data you write in Hbase goes through the following stages
Put -> WAL -> memstore -> HFile. The HFile is the actual file that is stored in HDFS. This is where the above name node and data node comes in. And HFile is sorted.

The sorting operation is done in Memstore, during which after reaching certain buffer size, it flushes to HFile.

Now to avoid data loss present in memstore, WALs are used.

You can get detailed info [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/06/hbase-write-path/)

Comment: You don't get my question. I understand why write ahead log is needed. I just don't understand how it can be implemented correctly over HDFS, because HDFS client doesn't flush immediately to data node but when the local client buffer became close to blocksize (by default 64MB). So If I put just one record to HBASE it would be of a very small size

Comment: HDFS block and Hbase block are different, and HBase block is around 64KB and HDFS is ar 64MB. respective flushing occurs when their block size is being reached. Some info [here](http://www.larsgeorge.com/2010/01/hbase-architecture-101-write-ahead-log.html). Loosing WAL means, eventually a region server failure. So then, when we restart the region server, it replays the records which are not flushed to mem store, and then writes them and move ahead. I hope the different block size and WAL replay information helped you to understand

Comment: Blocks are different but hbase WAL is a hadoop file which is stored in HDFS. Hbase doesn't play in this level. File flushing to hdfs is totally responsibility of HDFS client . Another question: if we couldn't restart region server due to node storage error? We lost our record in wal?

Comment: So here is Hbase not the client of HBase? Since WAL is also stored in HDFS, the replication factors come in, and in theory, definitely if region server is totally gone, may be we will loose record. However, there are always restoring mechanisms

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the flush interval. Hoep this link helps:
http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/perf.writing.html